# Commit all changes after executing playbook

Tags: network-programming, ansible, juniper

I made an Ansible play book that loops through a .yaml file and adds descriptions to interfaces. The problem is after every set command Ansible commits, waits for the commit then configures the next interface. If I run this on a VC with 10 members it will take for ever. Any one know how to make the playbook commit only after all changes have been made?

```
---
- name: Change configuration using junos_config module
  hosts: test
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_vars: /home/ansible/interfaces.yaml
  - name: Change description on interfaces based on a list of variable
    junos_config:
      lines:
        - "set interfaces {{ item.name }} description \"{{ item.description }}\""
     comment: "Update description of interface {{ item.name }}"
   with_items: "{{ interfaces }}"
   register: result

  - debug: var=result
```

I changed the play book which now looks like this:

```
---
- name: Change configuration using junos_config module
  hosts: test
  connection: local
  gather_facts: no
  tasks:
  - include_vars: /home/ansible/playbook-core/interfaces.yaml
  - name: Change description on interfaces based on a list of variable
    junos_config:
      lines:
        - "{{ lines_template }}"
        - "set interfaces {{ item.name }} description \"{{ item.description }}\""
      comment: "Update description of port"
    vars:
      lines_template: "[ {% for interface in interfaces %}'set interfaces {{ item.name }} description \"{{ item.description }}\"',{% endfor %} ]"
    with_items: "{{ interfaces }}"
    register: result

  - debug: var=result
```

And when I run it I get an error:

```
An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -
vvv. The error was: TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found
failed: [10.63.255.71] (item={u'name': u'ge-0/0/1', u'description': u'Set by 
ansible'}) => {"changed": false, "item": {"description": "Set by ansible", 
"name": "ge-0/0/1"}, "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent ca               
ll last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_wVNymo/ansible_module_junos_config.py\", 
line 402, in <module>\n    main()\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_wVNymo/ansible_module_junos_config.py\", line 371, in main\n    
diff = configure_device(module, warnings, candidate)\n  File 
\"/tmp/ansible_wVNymo/ansible_module_junos_config.py\", line 293, in 
configure_device\nreturn load_config(module, candidate, warnings, **kwargs)\n  
File \"/tmp/ansible_wVNy               
mo/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/junos.py\", line 199, in 
load_config\nTypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, list found\n", 
"module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the loop logic to Jinja2 template:

```
- name: Change description on interfaces based on a list of variable
  junos_config:
    lines: "{{ lines_template }}"
      - "set interfaces {{ item.name }} description \"{{ item.description }}\""
    comment: "Update description of interfaces"
  vars:
    lines_template: "[ {% for interface in interfaces %}'set interfaces {{ interface.name }} description \"{{ interface.description }}\"',{% endfor %} ]"
```

<sup>Last `,` could be skipped, but it seems Ansible makes up for that.</sup>

<sup>The above code is not tested with Juniper, but it should produce what you wanted.</sup>